# RestKit - cancelling all requests and stop all mapping operations

Tags: ios, restkit

I am creating an app that fetches a lot of data from server, and restkit takes substantial amount of time to map all the data.
Now if user logs out from the app, I want to cancel all remaining requests and cancel all the mapping of the downloaded data.

I tried to use

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].requestQueue cancelAllRequests];
```

But, this just stops subsequent requests but doesn't stops mapping of already downloaded data.

How can I do this ?
I am using RestKit V0.10.

Comment: I am using this api: `[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] cancelAllObjectRequestOperationsWithMethod:RKRequestMethodAny matchingPathPattern: THE_PATTERN]`, but I don't think this is the right answer.

Comment: This method doesn't exist in V0.20 :(

Comment: This is the version I use: RestKit (0.20.0pre4). And I use CocoaPods to install RestKit

Comment: Hey Ray, I'm sorry, I am on V0.10.